# WS.url fails when proxy options are set in Play Framework 2.2.x

Tags: java, playframework, proxy, playframework-2.2, http-status-code-407

I am using WS to make a REST call to a server behind a proxy that required.

I tried to set proxyserver and port in application.conf and as JVM arg when I launch the application. But I keep getting "Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required".

I tried to set ws.useProxyProperties at false and true, but it still doesn't work. I saw that it is a common problem, but no workaround has been published.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by using the dependancy

```
"com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.8.14"
```

And changing my code to

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setProxyServer(new 
ProxyServer(host, port, user, pwd)).build();
c = new AsyncHttpClient(cf);
AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder req = c.prepareGet("http://api.example.com/");
// and many other parameters ...
```